# Google App Engine and key-value stores

Tags: google-app-engine, redis, store

I am looking at various options for developing a web app in the cloud and have been looking at  GAE using Python. It has everything I need to develop the application. But I can not find a key-value store for it. In particular a key-value store that can scale. I have been looking at Redis but it is used for rails....

I have 2 questions regarding this.

1) Is a key-value store really needed for a high performance web app running on GAE?

2) Are there any well supported key-value stores for GAE?

All help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not really relevant to a good answer to your question, but there is nothing about Redis that links it to Rails. It has a pretty straightforward interface that can and has been wrapped for a variety of languages: http://redis.io/clients

Comment: what are you planning on using a key value store for?  You seem unsure as to whether you need one or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google App Engine comes with a high performance, scalable [Datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html) implementation.

It also has support for a [Memcached](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/) (key-value) implementation. It is up to your requirements for scale and functionality of the application which of the two options you chose.